# SOAP - leave only parent/root namespace

Tags: java, spring, soap, jaxb

I have several xsd files which are used to create a composition of one SOAP message.
The problem is that whenever object is build it imports all inherited xmlns. I didn't found anything about this problem. Is there any way to leave only root xmlns?

Example:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <testRes xmlns="http://xxx/xxx/xxx/v1" xmlns:ns2="http://yyy/yyy/yyy/v1" xmlns:ns3="http://zzz/zzz/zzz/v1">
         <status>B</status>
         <opisBledu>Error msg...</opisBledu>
      </testRes>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I need the message to be:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <testRes xmlns="http://xxx/xxx/xxx/v1"
         <status>B</status>
         <opisBledu>Error msg...</opisBledu>
      </testRes>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

There is need that
**xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" from S:Envelope**
and **xmlns:ns2="http://yyy/yyy/yyy/v1" xmlns:ns3="http://zzz/zzz/zzz/v1" from testRes** has to be removed.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can specify xmlns inside annotations `@XmlRootElement` `@XmlElement` `@XmlType` in your classes or inside `package-info.java`.
For example:

```
@XmlRootElement (name = "testRes", namespace = "http://xxx/xxx/xxx/v1")
public class TestRes
```

In your case need to remove unnecessary definitions